# Elegant way to find the roots of a Quartic

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I need to find the roots of this quartic: $y=x^4+6x^3+11x^2+6x-24024$ in order to be able to solve my problem.

I'm wondering if there's a nice easy way to find its roots (such as substituting $x$ with something). I do know the Rational Root Theorem, but I feel like listing out the factors of $24024$ would take too long.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may notice that
$$ x^4+6x^3+11x^2+6x-24024 = (x^2+3x+1)^2-24025 = (x^2+3x+1)^2-155^2 $$
by looking for the square of a second degree polynomial that matches the coefficients pattern $1,6,11$. It goes so smooth that the identity $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$ also provides a factorization:
$$\boxed{ x^4+6x^3+11x^2+6x-24024 = \color{blue}{(x-11)(x+14)}\color{green}{(x^2+3x+156)}.}$$

The fact that $24024$ is exceptionally close to an integer square and $x^4+6x^3+11x^2+6x+1$ is a palyndromic polynomial (hence $x^2$ times a quadratic polynomial in the variable $x+\frac{1}{x}$) **and** a square leads to an alternative, equivalent solution.

Comment: @Crescendo: *write it as a difference of two squares* is a simple criterion for providing factorizations (that is the core of the quadratic sieve, for instance). With that knowledge, I simply tried to do what I wrote: find a second degree polynomial whose square "begins" with $x^4+6x^3+11x^2$.

Comment: Wait, I'm still kind of confused. $115^2$ does not equal $24024$... and expanding out $(x^2+3x+1)^2-115^2$ gives me $x^4+6x^3+11x^2+6x-13224$

Comment: @Crescendo: I exploited $24024=\color{red}{155}^2-1$.

Comment: $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$ is used so much for its elegance IMO.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio Ah! So can any polynomial with coefficients such as above $a,b,a$ be rewritten as a difference of two squares?

Comment: @Crescendo: probably you mean to ask if every palyndromic polynomial like $x^4+6x^3+11x^2+6x+1$ **is** a square. The answer, in general, is clearly no (the discriminant of a palyndromic polynomial can be different from zero), but in this particular case we are lucky, the mentioned polynomial is just the square of $x^2+3x+1$.